# Unable to connect dispatch to props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a class component that I want to connect to the store in order to pull data.

I have tested the action with a function component and it was working well. Due to some limitations, I decided to use a class component.

The problem is that 'getTableDataAction' does not exist despite the fact that I did connect the dispatch via connect function.

As a result I will get the foolowing error:"**TypeError: this.props.getTableDataAction is not a function**"

```
 export default class TchExportButton extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedIndex: 0,
        anchorEl: null,
        options: ['Select drill down report',
            'Destroyed DCA',
            'Repaired - A008']
    }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    if (this.state.selectedIndex !== prevState.selectedIndex) {
        if (this.state.selectedIndex > 0) {
            this.props.getTableDataAction(this.state.selectedIndex)
        }
    }
}
.....
...
..

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    data: state.tchCommecialTableData.data,
    }
 }


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return {
    getTableDataAction: (buttonId) => dispatch(engineeringDataAction.getTableDataAction(buttonId))
   }
}

 connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but something is missing there and I can't find the root cause.

Any idea what is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You have the `connect` at the bottom just by itself, are you exporting the connected component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default export should be the connected component, not the unconnected component.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TchExportButton);
```

(Make sure to remove the export default at the top)

Comment: This is the answer. Why? `connect` is a higher-order-component: in short, you pass a component as an argument, and it returns a component.

see https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: Hi Nick and thank you for your answer, I cant use higher-order component due to a problem with material-ui/Slide component (TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null). see https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#caveat-with-refs. Any other option for export?

Answer (score 1):

Define class and export connect(class):

```
class TchExportButton extends Component
```

export:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TchExportButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to what the other guys have answered, connect is a function that returns a function which in turn returns a component. In react-redux, connect is probably something like this:

```
function connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, ...other arguments){
      return function(Component){
         ...
      }
}
```

It's definitely more complicated than this but this is the core concept of calling

`connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)`
as the first function call calls the first function and the second calls the returned function.